# What do you think of an employer that requires posting Glassdoor reviews while "on the bench"?

Tags: ethics

The company I work for is small, and since posting a review on Glassdoor is required as a "bench task", it will be obvious who posted the review. I'd like to be honest, for 2 reasons: 1 - to help potential employees know what they are getting into, and 
2 - to help the company itself better understand some of the issues they need to address. However, since I have been asked for "feedback on how to make  better" by HR in the past, and I have given the feedback that would be in the review, and the important criticism (with suggestions on how to "fix" the issues) has been ignored (they have taken several of my suggestions), I am wondering what others think of this issue. Opinions are welcome.

I'd like to be clear that I am not seeking legal advice. This "required task" is simply that - a tick box on a very recently created form. There is no written company policy regarding bench tasks. I have asked to meet with the HR resource, either in person or by phone, but with both of our schedules, it may not happen until I am on the bench.

I do have queries out to ex-coworkers and friends regarding this issue. Some responses have been "they used to do this at my company" and "we all refused to do this, so they stopped asking", so it seems like this may be a new trend.

TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure what the phrases "on the bench" or "bench task" mean.

Comment: @DavidK In consultancies and similar business models it refers to unproductive time, where you may be between projects for example. The phrase is a sports reference.

Comment: @user29226 - Is this paid bench time or unpaid?  It makes a difference in the answer.

Comment: It is paid bench time.

Comment: I will reword my question. I am not seeking legal advice.

Answer (score 8):

They most certainly can require you to post something on Glassdoor or another site (at least in the US where most employment is at-will). Is it ethical? Not in the least.

Take heart that for companies I've known of that do this, others have posted complaints (on the same place you're required to post your positive post) that state just what you're saying, which is that employees are required to add positive posts.

The end result is that the company actually makes itself look worse and increases the number of negative posts. Additionally, it annoys people like you who feel compelled to do it so it becomes lose-lose.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Chris. I've thought of reviewing them now, before my "required" review, and state what is required of employees in that review. Hoping that at this point, they won't be able to ID who is posting. I'm fairly sure I can disguise the posting enough to protect myself. Since the business area they operate in is small, I don't want to end up with any negative blowback. Thanks again.

Comment: Or have someone else type up your "pre-review" on your behalf so you don't risk any markers in how you type.

Comment: A company directing an employee to post a review without full disclosure may well violate the US FTC's regulations on online reviews: http://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2009/10/ftc-publishes-final-guides-governing-endorsements-testimonials

Comment: I would just do it when they ask me to do it and I would be honest in my review, including mentioning the fact that I was required to post the review on my own time. And if that made you worry that you would receive future requests to do work on your own time, I would say so. If they get upset at you for being honest in a review, update your review to say that too.